# Привязал для кнопки QMessageBox (через функцию), но срабатывает без нажатия

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qmessagebox

Хочу сделать на кнопку вызов `QMessageBox`, создаю под него функцию, привязываю через `ui.btn.clicked.connect(QMB)` и функция вызывается сама, следом за выходом из `QMessageBox` происходит вылет программы.
Что делать?

Вот код:

```
ui.KeyboardClicker.clicked.connect(ErrorOfInput('ывафыаваывп', 'фывакпыавп'))
```

```
def ErrorOfInput(ErrorMessage, WhatWrong):
    Err = QMessageBox()
    Err.setWindowTitle(ErrorMessage)
    Err.setText(WhatWrong)
    Err.exec_()
```

Comment: Добавьте lambda и все заработает `ui.KeyboardClicker.clicked.connect(lambda: ErrorOfInput('ывафыаваывп', 'фывакпыавп'))`

Comment: Вот это я думаю не нужно Err.exec_(), а это надо добавить Err.show() наверное.

Comment: Александр, Я Хочу Вызывать, А Не Показывать Просто Без Нажатия, Вот В Чем Прикол

Comment: Alexander, Спасиба

Comment: CoCuCka вопрос решен или нет? Если нет, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Рещен, Щас Попробую Закрыть Вопрос